# Requesting a simple way to align a text in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Hello I am  pretty new to react native and i am trying to align a text in react native using property text align vertical top but i cannot seem to understand what i am doing wrong

The HI there & welcome text should be align a little top

```html
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";

export default class SignUp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.signup}>
        <Text style={styles.Text} />
        <Text style={styles.string}>Hi There!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.string}>Welcome</Text>
        <Text style={styles.Text}>FULL NAME</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textinput}
          placeholder="Please Enter Your Name"
          underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
        />
        <Text style={styles.Text}>EMAIL</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textinput}
          placeholder="Please Enter Your Email"
          underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
          keyboardType="email-address"
        />
        <Text style={styles.Text}>PASSWORD</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textinput}
          placeholder="Please Enter Your Password"
          secureTextEntry={true}
          underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
        />
        <Text style={styles.Text}>MOBILE NUMER</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textinput}
          placeholder="Please Enter Your Mobile Number"
          underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
          keyboardType="numeric"
        />
        <Text style={styles.Text}>CNIC</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textinput}
          placeholder="Please Enter Your CNIC"
          underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
          keyboardType="numeric"
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.btntext}>Sign Up</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  signup: {
    alignSelf: "stretch",
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: "#6069f2",
    paddingBottom: 10,
    marginBottom: 40,
    borderBottomColor: "#199187",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
  textinput: {
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    height: 40,
    marginBottom: 30,
    color: "#1D1105",
    borderBottomColor: "#f8f8f8",
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
  },
  button: {
    alignSelf: "stretch",
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#6069f2",
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  btntext: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  string: {
    textAlignVertical: "top",
  },
});
```

[image]

Its a SignIn/SignUp page for a project i am working on

Answer (score 0):

Since React Native works with flex box model by default, you could try to do it using one of these:

```
justifyContent: 'flex-start';

alignItems: 'flex-start';
```

And also setting a height to the container.

Comment: can you help me please

Comment: how can I help you?

Comment: i need a little guidence on how do i place my text on left side